# PHP session doesn't persist on new server

Tags: php, ajax, session

First off, I did read at least 10 similarly named questions and answers and did not resolve the issue.

I had a working AJAX-based login script, but now that I've copy-pasted the entire site to new hosting, it doesn't work.

The process is simple.

Javascript sends login data to `ajax.php`, where this happens:

```
session_start();

//check database

$_SESSION['isloggedin']=1;
//if I var_dump($_SESSION) here, it prints out `array{'isloggedin' => 1}`

echo "ok";
```

Then Javascript redirects to `index.php`, which is currently:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

But here, `$_SESSION` is an empty array!

If I do `echo session_id();` on both pages, it prints out the same value.

What could possibly be the issue here?

Remember, it worked perfectly on a different server.

Comment: Do you use `exit` or `die` prematurely? That will sometimes result in Sessions not getting persisted.

Comment: There's no exit or die anywhere in either file.

Comment: Show versions of PHP on both servers, also "session.*" ini options would be helpful.

Comment: The old server is 5.5.29, the new one is 5.3.3 - but surely basic session functionality should be identical? here's a pastebin with session.* php.ini settings for both servers: http://pastebin.com/jM27JDdx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried basic session increment test by reloading one page in the browser? For example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

Is it working?

If you store session data in files (default PHP configuration):
Can you access folder, where session files are stored? Is anything stored in session file, that assigned to your session?

Comment: Nope, the counter is 0 on every reload.

Comment: Try to run upload and run `phpinfo()` to review session configuration on your server. For more info [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

If you are using default PHP Session configuration, try to check **session.save_path** settings [more](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) - is this present in your config? Is it pointing to valid directory? Can PHP write into that directory.

Comment: As I see from thread above, please check do the folder `/var/lib/php/session` exists and is it writable by the user used to run PHP. By the way, have you tried to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your testing scripts - any new messages with this settings?

Answer (score -2):

first thing is in which page you use session you have to write
first line is ***session_start()***
ok?

please try this i hope your problem solve

Comment: <?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['session123']="Demo";
     echo $_SESSION['session123'];
?>
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['session123']))
{
  echo $_SESSION['session123'];
}
?>